# android RelativeLayout below not working

Tags: android, android-scrollview, android-relativelayout

I have main RelativeLayout layout file. I have scrollview and  two buttons and listview inside this scrollview.I have one problem , when i run program it show's only one item in listview.my problem is xml file. How i can change my problem?

```
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="wrap_content"
android:orientation="vertical" >


<ScrollView

    android:id="@+id/scrollview"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"

     >



<RelativeLayout
    android:id="@+id/layout"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_marginTop="50dp"
    android:background="#5f2585" >

    <Button
        android:id="@+id/studia"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="50dp"
        android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
        android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
        android:background="@drawable/n_button"
        android:text="სტუდია"
        android:textColor="#ffffff" />

    <ListView
        android:id="@+id/menu_listview"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_below="@+id/studia"
        android:divider="@null"

         >
    </ListView>

    <Button
        android:id="@+id/gadacema"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="40dp"
        android:layout_below="@+id/menu_listview"
        android:background="@drawable/n_button"
        android:text="გადაცემა"
        android:textColor="#ffffff" />
</RelativeLayout>
```

in programmatically everything is ok(if i deleted scrollview,then i can show all values,but i cannot show button witch is a below in listview

What is wrong in my xml file. How can i solve this problem?

Comment: It is generally not a good idea to have nested scroll views (`ScrollView` and `ListView`), are you sure you need this? Then, your `LinearLayout` is useless as it only has one child which is a `ScrollView`. Try to create your XML as simple as possible. It will be easier for you to find the errors and it is better for the performances.

Answer (score 2):

Please try this.

```
<ScrollView xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent"
>


<LinearLayout
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:orientation="vertical" 
     >



<RelativeLayout
    android:id="@+id/layout"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_marginTop="50dp"
    android:background="#5f2585" >

    <Button
        android:id="@+id/studia"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="50dp"
        android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
        android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
        android:background="@drawable/n_button"
        android:text="სტუდია"
        android:textColor="#ffffff" />

    <ListView
        android:id="@+id/menu_listview"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:layout_below="@+id/studia"
        android:divider="@null"

         >
    </ListView>

    <Button
        android:id="@+id/gadacema"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="40dp"
        android:layout_below="@+id/menu_listview"
        android:background="@drawable/n_button"
        android:text="გადაცემა"
        android:textColor="#ffffff" />
</RelativeLayout>
</LinearLayout>
</ScrollView>
```

Comment: i think you have to change list view height `android:layout_height="match_parent"`

Answer (score 0):

Try this:-

```
    <RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
     >
        <Button
            android:id="@+id/studia"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="50dp"
            android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
            android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
            android:background="@drawable/n_button"
            android:text="სტუდია"
            android:textColor="#ffffff" />

        <ListView
            android:id="@+id/menu_listview"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_below="@+id/studia"
            android:divider="@null"/>


        <Button
            android:id="@+id/gadacema"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="40dp"
            android:layout_below="@+id/menu_listview"
            android:background="@drawable/n_button"
            android:text="გადაცემა"
            android:textColor="#ffffff" />

</RelativeLayout>
```